# Keeping configuration of snaps when they auto-upgrade

Tags: upgrade, snap

I've run into an annoying issue recently. Every time a snap auto-upgrades, its configuration is completely reset. E.g. when Blender/OBS/RetroArch auto-update, all configuration is lost, and I can't seem to find the previous configuration files. This has resulted in me losing all my OBS scene configurations among other things.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? Or to somehow use the configuration from the older version of the snap? (Assuming it's still somewhere on my disk, hopefully)

Comment: Are you saying that configuration files in your /home are deleted? Or are you changing configuration files someplace else?

Comment: @user535733 I'm not sure where snap apps store their configuration files, but every time the snaps update, the configuration files are lost. I'm not changing them manually, they're used by the snaps themselves. Think stuff like viewport options and addons in Blender, scene configurations in OBS, emulator options in RetroArch, etc.

Comment: Can't say anything useful about Blender but I've been using Firefox snap for a year now. Upgrades itself smoothly without loss of profiles or anything else. Your issue may be specific not to snaps but to Blender's usage of them. I'd start with daily backups of Blender configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-migrating configuration seems like a missing feature in the OBS snap, but I was able to manually copy over my config. My snap dir looked looks like this:

```
~/snap/obs-studio$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 4 neilenm domain^users 4096 Jun  1 10:29 1195
drwxr-xr-x 5 neilenm domain^users 4096 Jun  2 10:23 1251
drwxr-xr-x 3 neilenm domain^users 4096 Apr 12 09:37 common
lrwxrwxrwx 1 neilenm domain^users    4 Jun  2 10:15 current -> 1251
```

The `1195` directory contained my old OBS with my scenes, `1251` is the new one. I moved the config in `1251` out of the way and copied over the config from `1195`:

```
~/snap/obs-studio$ cd 1251/
~/snap/obs-studio/1251$ ls -a
.  ..  .config  .last_revision  .local  .themes
~/snap/obs-studio/1251$ mv .config .config.bak
~/snap/obs-studio/1251$ cp -r ../1195/.config .
~/snap/obs-studio/1251$ ls -a
.  ..  .config  .config.bak  .last_revision  .local  .themes
```

After this I had my previously configured scenes back in OBS.